# How to restrict access to web pages for different types of users?

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application where there is one admin and many users. When a user logs in he is taken to a certain page from which he can perform other operations which lead him to other pages restricted to him .The same goes for the admin too. But if i change the url to the restricted page during runtime a user can access an admin's page and vice versa. I have heard about using membership access. But i dont know how its done. I am  using an sql database where the login details are stored in a table.

So how do i restrict access? I have heard it has to do something with the web.config? Is it possible to achieve the same result by using just code behind?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ASP.NET Membership provider. It will give you a lot of stuff out of the box. There's a [good tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs) by Scott Mitchell that will guide you through this process.

- [Part 1](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs)
- [Part 2](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-user-accounts-cs)
- [Part 3](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/validating-user-credentials-against-the-membership-user-store-cs)
- [Part 4](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/user-based-authorization-cs)
- [Part 5](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/storing-additional-user-information-cs)

Comment: I added two roles from the WSAT , one called "member" and the other called "admin". I want to add an userid (which is entered into a textbox) into a role from code behind. I tried to use Roles.AddUserToRole(userid_tb.Text,"member"); . But it didnt work.. Where have i commited the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

When loading your pages, you might have to check if the user have the right permission and allow access or redirect him to another page.

If ! user can access page {
   redirect 
}

Your page content.

Comment: My doubt is why cant i use Roles.AddUserToRole(). and a user to a role