# how to create privileges for users in a asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a MS-SQL database with **users table** and login page and everything, i wanna restrict access to some pages to couple users only.

i want something like this

```
@if (WebSecurity.privilegs == "administrative")
   view page;
else
   Redirect;
```

**What should i use to implement such a thing ?**

** im building asp.net webforms not MVC

Comment: This tutorial will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10544300/5167809

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Authentication and add Authorization Roles through database - MVC asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589863/windows-authentication-and-add-authorization-roles-through-database-mvc-asp-ne)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the built in ASP.NET Identity and then assign a role your users. You then secure your application based on roles.